MetricReader can not be bound to a MeterProvider again
I am trying to use otel metrics for my nestjs application.
getting the Error:
MetricReader can not be bound to a MeterProvider again.
    at PeriodicExportingMetricReader.setMetricProducer (/Users//metrics-otel/node_modules/@opentelemetry/sdk-metrics/src/export/MetricReader.ts:93:13)
    at MeterProvider.addMetricReader (/Users/metrics-otel/node_modules/@opentelemetry/sdk-metrics/src/MeterProvider.ts:97:18)
    at new MeterProvider (/Users/metrics-otel/node_modules/@opentelemetry/sdk-metrics/src/MeterProvider.ts:61:14)
    at NodeSDK.start (/Users/metrics-otel/node_modules/@opentelemetry/sdk-node/src/sdk.ts:279:29)
    at bootstrap (/Users/metrics-otel/src/main.ts:6:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/metrics-otel/src/main.ts:10:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)

steps to reproduce:

run command nest new project-name
under src touch metrics.ts



/*instrumentation.ts*/
import { NodeSDK } from '@opentelemetry/sdk-node';
import { ConsoleSpanExporter } from '@opentelemetry/sdk-trace-node';
import { getNodeAutoInstrumentations } from '@opentelemetry/auto-instrumentations-node';
import {
  PeriodicExportingMetricReader,
  ConsoleMetricExporter,
} from '@opentelemetry/sdk-metrics';

export const otelSDK = new NodeSDK({
  traceExporter: new ConsoleSpanExporter(),
  metricReader: new PeriodicExportingMetricReader({
    exporter: new ConsoleMetricExporter(),
  }),
  instrumentations: [getNodeAutoInstrumentations()],
});

otelSDK.start();



main.ts


import { otelSDK } from './metrics';
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  await otelSDK.start();
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();



my package.json looks like this
"dependencies": {
"@opentelemetry/api": "^1.8.0",
"@opentelemetry/auto-instrumentations-node": "^0.46.1",
"@opentelemetry/sdk-metrics": "^1.24.1",
"@opentelemetry/sdk-node": "^0.51.1",
"@opentelemetry/sdk-trace-node": "^1.24.1",
},
doc which i followed -> https://opentelemetry.io/docs/languages/js/getting-started/nodejs/

please edit your question to show us the entire stack trace of the error

updated with entire stack trace of the error

@MicaelLevi any idea on this?

I've no ideia. Never used that lib before

You're starting the NodeSDK twice.
The first time is in your instrumentation.ts when you call otelSDK.start();.
The second time is when you call await otelSDK.start(); in your main.ts.
Solution 1
Remove otelSDK.start(); from your instrumentation.ts file.
Solution 2
Remove await otelSDK.start(); in your main.ts in your bootstrap(); function.
Explanation
When you create a new NodeSDK object you pass MetricReader.
So if you don't call the otelSDK.start() function the MetricReader will not have a provider.
MeterProvider is the entry point of the API. It provides access to Meters.
Each reader should have only one MetricProvider. MetricProvider has the function shutdown which should close every Reader and Meter. And if MetricReader could have more than one Provider you will have a situation when you return a closed Meter.
That is why MeterReader has validation if it already has a Provider.
